# Editable JComboBox Search

Tags: java, swing, search, autocomplete, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox which contains a whole heap of people in it. When I click that person it then shows me all the data associated with those people. This is stored in a LinkedList of LinkedLists. I want to make it so that my JComboBox can be used to search for the people in the LinkedList as well as using the drop down menu in it.

How would I need to change my current code to implement this?

```
    clientList = new JComboBox<String>(myOLL.toArray());
    clientList.setEditable(true);

    clientList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            clientList.getSelectedItem();
            int indexToUse = clientList.getSelectedIndex();

            LinkedList jobList = myOLL.returnList(indexToUse);

            txtOutput.setText(jobList.toString());
        }
    });
    clientList.setBounds(95, 10, 329, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(clientList);
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: You would need to specify the editor to be used by the `JComboBox`, see [`JComboBox#setEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setEditor(javax.swing.ComboBoxEditor)).  This editor would need to be able to find the index of the value which most closely matched what you were typing...You could also have a look at the [Auto-Completion Support](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/19/adding-auto-completion-to-swing-comboboxes.html) from [SwingLabs SwingX API](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases)